# Best practice to install proxmox (7 or newer) on server

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, software-raid, proxmox

i did a lot of research and i am still wondering, where to install os (proxmox). We have ProLiant DL560 gen8 and gen9.
My options:

1. micro SD card 32/64GB, not good because of lots of writings from
   proxmox
2. usb 32/64GB
3. 2x SAS disk 300/400GB, RAID1 through pci raid controller
4. 2x SAS disk 300/400GB, through pci raid controller, but zraid1 in
   Proxmox
5. 2x SSD disk 250/512GB, RAID1 through pci raid controller, probably
   not good because of lots of writings from proxmox
6. 2x SSD disk 250/512GB, through pci raid controller, but zraid1 in
   Proxmox
7. 2x NVME M2 disk 250GB, RAID1 through pci raid controller
8. 2x NVME M2 disk 250GB, through pci raid controller, but zraid1 in
   Proxmox
9. 2x NVME M2 disk 250GB, on pci, M2 NVME to PCIe Adapter 2x cards ,
   but zraid1 in Proxmox

I would like to know pros/cons of this options, or if there are some other suggestions.
For vms we have SAN and fiber SW.

Answer (score 1):

I would not install Proxmox, but in this case I'd go with putting it on your SAS disks and reserve your SSDs and NVME disks for VMs

Comment: Option number 3 or 4?

Comment: Option 3 - but I would not do a hypervisor installation on a RAID1 configuration. I'd try and see if I could make a RAID5 configuration instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would install Proxmox.

So this is just for the Hypervisor installation and the VMs will live elsewhere....

DO NOT use USB or an SD card.

> because of lots of writings from proxmox

No, the the hypervisor does not generate a lot of I/O unless you expect it to be operating in swap (which is very bad). However you do want something which is reliable (implying RAID and a stable attachement). You really don't need the performance beyond spinning rust, so it comes down to a question of price and ease of swapping.

Easy swapping probably rules out NVME (although I believe that physical capability for hotswap is starting to become available).

You don't need a lot of space for the hypervisor either - 250Gb is plenty.

Software RAID usually makes a lot more sense that hardware RAID. The possible exception is if you have all your disks in warranty and BBU on the RAID. If that's not the case, you want the RAID card set up in IT Mode. And the default installer for Proxmox will only provision ZFS as RAID.

Comment: How do you guys have?